# NameError: uninitialized constant SingleColumnValueFilter

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I am trying to use hbase filter using this code,

hbase(main):001:0> scan 'students', { FILTER => SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('account'),Bytes.toBytes('name'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),BinaryComparator.new(Bytes.toBytes('emp1')))}

and this code give the error like,
**NameError: uninitialized constant SingleColumnValueFilter**

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or what I need to do for get filter result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.BinaryComparator;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter;
    hbase(main):009:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter. Filter;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this instead of importing:

```
scan 'students', {FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('account', 'name', =, 'binary:emp1')"}
```